# POSIX sed replacement on multiline

Tags: sed

I'm trying to get this to work and I'm at a loss now:

I have a named.conf file.  In it, I have line pattern:

```
/*
        forwarders {
                127.0.0.1;
        };
*/
```

I would like to use sed to remove the beginning /* and ending */ and to replace 127.0.0.1; with 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4;

I don't care if I have to write out intermediate files on the way.  In fact I do that on multiple iterations to see where things fail as my full script does that upon each substitution in the file to see where things might fail.

I was trying the simplest part of this.  Detect the forwarders and feed the next line to see if the 127.0.0.1 existed and replace it.

```
sed -e '/forwarders/ 
n       
/'127.0.0.1;'/'8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4;'/' named.conf.1 > named.conf.2
```

This is POSIX sed from BSD/MacOSX, not GNU sed with it's non-portable extensions.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: BSD `sed`, though closer to the active standard, has its own set of non-portable extensions.  Some of which are compatible with GNU `sed`.

Comment: I don't believe that is true.  BSD sed has only the POSIX commands/flags to work on regex.  GNU adds more that aren't in the POSIX standard.  From the man page:  sed [-Ealnr] [-e command] [-f command_file] [-I extension] [-i extension]
         [file ...]    Please NOTE:  You can make it 'compatible with GNU sed' however, this leads to, again, not being able to move it onto POSIX machines.

Comment: From the FreeBSD 12-CURRENT man page: `The -E, -I, -a and -i options, the prefixing “+” in the second member of an address range, as well as the “I” flag to the address regular expression and substitution command are non-standard FreeBSD extensions and may not be available on other operating systems.`  Current BSD  based `sed` implementations all have a similar passage.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see that in the lowest part of the man page.  However, again, I try not to use those very flags.  I try to stick with the standard POSIX sed for portability.

Answer (score 1):

sed is for simple susbtitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk. This will work in any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$0 == "/*" { inCmt=1 }
inCmt { cmt = (inCmt++ > 1 ? cmt ORS : "") $0 }
$0 == "*/" {
    if (cmt ~ /forwarders/) {
        sub(/127\.0\.0\.1;/,"8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4;",cmt)
        gsub(/^[^\n]+\n|\n[^\n]+$/,"",cmt)
    }
    $0 = cmt
    inCmt=0
}
!inCmt { print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4;
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be made into a substitution by consuming the entire comment, and substituting over multiple lines.

```
\|^/\*$| {
        :l
        N
        \|\*/$|!bl
        s|^/\*\(.*forwarders[[:space:]]*{[[:space:]]*\)127\.0\.0\.1\(.*\)\*/|\18.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4\2|
}
```

Note that embedded and quoted comments will break a simple parser, such as this, and if such robustness is needed a more powerful tool should be used.